# ValueError: ('Transaction %r is not open on this connection', <py2neo.client.http.HTTPTransaction object at 0x7fe3fe8f9e80>)

Tags: python, heroku, neo4j, py2neo, graphenedb

I am developing a webapp using the library py2neo.

I also pushed it on Heroku, where it is connected with a Graphene DB, while locally it is connected with a Neo4j database.

As I was using my webapp on Heroku, I got this error:

```
ValueError: ('Transaction %r is not open on this connection', <py2neo.client.http.HTTPTransaction object at 0x7fe3fe8f9e80>)
```

Since I still have `debug=True`, I can see that the error happened when the webapp tryed to merge a relationship

```
rel = Relationship(...
graph.merge(rel)
```

This error happed once, and then did not occurr anymore.
However, what does the error mean?

I cant't understand the [documentation](https://py2neo.org/2020.0/_modules/py2neo/client/bolt.html) for this error:

> ```
> def _assert_transaction_open(self, tx):
>     if tx is not self._transaction:
>         raise ValueError("Transaction %r is not open on this connection", tx)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore this. It's a bug which will be fixed in the next release.